# What does it mean when a method returns .Task for a TaskCompletionSource<bool> variable?

Tags: c#

Specifically for:

```
return tcsInitialize.Task;
```

in this class

```
internal class TextToSpeechImplementation 
{
    AndroidTextToSpeech tts;
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsInitialize;

    Task<bool> Initialize()
    {
        if (tcsInitialize != null && tts != null)
            return tcsInitialize.Task;

        tcsInitialize = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        try
        {
            tts = new AndroidTextToSpeech(MainActivity.Instance, this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tcsInitialize.SetException(e);
        }
        return tcsInitialize.Task;
    }
```

Should it not return a boolean true or false?

For reference here's the full class code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Speech.Tts;
using AndroidTextToSpeech = Android.Speech.Tts.TextToSpeech;
using Debug = System.Diagnostics.Debug;
using JavaLocale = Java.Util.Locale;

namespace Xamarin.Essentials
{
    public static partial class TextToSpeech
    {
        const int maxSpeechInputLengthDefault = 4000;

        static WeakReference<TextToSpeechImplementation> textToSpeechRef = null;

        static TextToSpeechImplementation GetTextToSpeech()
        {
            if (textToSpeechRef == null || !textToSpeechRef.TryGetTarget(out var tts))
            {
                tts = new TextToSpeechImplementation();
                textToSpeechRef = new WeakReference<TextToSpeechImplementation>(tts);
            }

            return tts;
        }

        internal static Task PlatformSpeakAsync(string text, SpeechOptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken = default)
        {
            var textToSpeech = GetTextToSpeech();

            if (textToSpeech == null)
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Unable to start text-to-speech engine, not supported on device.");

            var max = maxSpeechInputLengthDefault;
            if (Platform.HasApiLevel(BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr2))
                max = AndroidTextToSpeech.MaxSpeechInputLength;

            return textToSpeech.SpeakAsync(text, max, options, cancelToken);
        }

        internal static Task<IEnumerable<Locale>> PlatformGetLocalesAsync()
        {
            var textToSpeech = GetTextToSpeech();

            if (textToSpeech == null)
                throw new PlatformNotSupportedException("Unable to start text-to-speech engine, not supported on device.");

            return textToSpeech.GetLocalesAsync();
        }
    }

    internal class TextToSpeechImplementation : Java.Lang.Object, AndroidTextToSpeech.IOnInitListener,
#pragma warning disable CS0618
        AndroidTextToSpeech.IOnUtteranceCompletedListener
#pragma warning restore CS0618
    {
        AndroidTextToSpeech tts;
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsInitialize;
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcsUtterances;

        Task<bool> Initialize()
        {
            if (tcsInitialize != null && tts != null)
                return tcsInitialize.Task;

            tcsInitialize = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            try
            {
                // set up the TextToSpeech object
                tts = new AndroidTextToSpeech(Platform.AppContext, this);
#pragma warning disable CS0618
                tts.SetOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
#pragma warning restore CS0618

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                tcsInitialize.SetException(e);
            }

            return tcsInitialize.Task;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                tts?.Stop();
                tts?.Shutdown();
                tts = null;
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        int numExpectedUtterances = 0;
        int numCompletedUtterances = 0;

        public async Task SpeakAsync(string text, int max, SpeechOptions options, CancellationToken cancelToken)
        {
            await Initialize();

            // Wait for any previous calls to finish up
            if (tcsUtterances?.Task != null)
                await tcsUtterances.Task;

            if (cancelToken != null)
            {
                cancelToken.Register(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        tts?.Stop();

                        tcsUtterances?.TrySetResult(true);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                });
            }

            if (options?.Locale?.Language != null)
            {
                JavaLocale locale = null;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options?.Locale.Country))
                    locale = new JavaLocale(options.Locale.Language, options.Locale.Country);
                else
                    locale = new JavaLocale(options.Locale.Language);

                tts.SetLanguage(locale);
            }
            else
            {
                SetDefaultLanguage();
            }

            if (options?.Pitch.HasValue ?? false)
                tts.SetPitch(options.Pitch.Value);
            else
                tts.SetPitch(TextToSpeech.PitchDefault);

            var parts = text.SplitSpeak(max);

            numExpectedUtterances = parts.Count;
            tcsUtterances = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            for (var i = 0; i < parts.Count && !cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested; i++)
            {
                // We require the utterance id to be set if we want the completed listener to fire
                var map = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { AndroidTextToSpeech.Engine.KeyParamUtteranceId, $"{guid}.{i}" }
                };

                if (options != null && options.Volume.HasValue)
                    map.Add(AndroidTextToSpeech.Engine.KeyParamVolume, options.Volume.Value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

                // We use an obsolete overload here so it works on older API levels at runtime
                // Flush on first entry and add (to not flush our own previous) subsequent entries
#pragma warning disable CS0618
                tts.Speak(parts[i], i == 0 ? QueueMode.Flush : QueueMode.Add, map);
#pragma warning restore CS0618
            }

            await tcsUtterances.Task;
        }

        public void OnInit(OperationResult status)
        {
            if (status.Equals(OperationResult.Success))
                tcsInitialize.TrySetResult(true);
            else
                tcsInitialize.TrySetException(new ArgumentException("Failed to initialize Text to Speech engine."));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Locale>> GetLocalesAsync()
        {
            await Initialize();

            if (Platform.HasApiLevel(BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop))
            {
                try
                {
                    return tts.AvailableLanguages.Select(a => new Locale(a.Language, a.Country, a.DisplayName, string.Empty));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Unable to query language on new API, attempting older api: " + ex);
                }
            }

            return JavaLocale.GetAvailableLocales()
                .Where(IsLocaleAvailable)
                .Select(l => new Locale(l.Language, l.Country, l.DisplayName, string.Empty))
                .GroupBy(c => c.ToString())
                .Select(g => g.First());
        }

        private bool IsLocaleAvailable(JavaLocale l)
        {
            try
            {
                var r = tts.IsLanguageAvailable(l);
                return
                    r == LanguageAvailableResult.Available ||
                    r == LanguageAvailableResult.CountryAvailable ||
                    r == LanguageAvailableResult.CountryVarAvailable;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Error checking language; " + l + " " + ex);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public void OnUtteranceCompleted(string utteranceId)
        {
            numCompletedUtterances++;
            if (numCompletedUtterances >= numExpectedUtterances)
                tcsUtterances?.TrySetResult(true);
        }

#pragma warning disable 0618
        void SetDefaultLanguage()
        {
            if (Platform.HasApiLevel(BuildVersionCodes.JellyBeanMr2))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (tts.DefaultLanguage == null && tts.Language != null)
                        tts.SetLanguage(tts.Language);
                    else if (tts.DefaultLanguage != null)
                        tts.SetLanguage(tts.DefaultLanguage);
                }
                catch
                {
                    if (tts.Language != null)
                        tts.SetLanguage(tts.Language);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (tts.Language != null)
                    tts.SetLanguage(tts.Language);
            }
        }
#pragma warning restore 0618
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning `Task<T>` instead of `T` generally means an intention to make method awaitable. `TaskCompletionSource` is a mechanism which allows to wrap asynchronous APIs which don't directly support awaitable semantic into `async` `await` form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you cannot complete/cancel a `Task<TResult>` explicitly because its `SetResult`/etc. members are not public. But `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` exposes these features to you. So whenever you need to return a task, which must be completed 'manually' or when another event occurs, you can use a completion source.

Consider the following pseudo example:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<int> wheelOfFortuneCompletion;

private Task<int> GiveSomeNumberAsync()
{
    StartWheelOfFortuneAnimation();
    wheelOfFortuneCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    return wheelOfFortuneCompletion.Task; // this is an uncompleted task
}

private void WheelStopped(object sender, WheelOfFortuneEventArgs e)
{
    // the result of GiveSomeNumberAsync will be completed when this line is executed:
    wheelOfFortuneCompletion.SetResult(e.Value);
}

private void WheelBroken(object sender, WheelOfFortuneEventArgs e)
{
    wheelOfFortuneCompletion.SetException(new InvalidOperationException("Oops"));
}
```

In your original example `tcsInitialize` is completed in the `OnInit` method. Until that method is called, the returned task of the `Initialize` method is 'running'.

Answer (score 2):

For `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` `tcsInitialize.Task;` will return `Task<bool>` which fits the signature of the function.