# CancellationTokenSource not working as expected on a TaskCompletionSource

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I am trying to wrap a an event based call onto a Task using TaskCompletionSource, but for some reason this is not working as expected, when calling SendRequest with `await SendRequest(cmdid, data)` it never returns back no matter how hard I try to SetCanceled, SetResult, etc...

To make sure that the task would end before troubleshooting further, here below I am trying with a CancellationTokenSource, it does not seem to work as expected, am I misunderstanding the concept and usage of TaskCompletionSource and Cancellation?

My understanding is that the following code would throw an exception when the cancellation token that was attached to the tcs would expire after 1 second, but no, `await SendRequest(cmdid, data)` gets to block forever.

```
        public async Task<object> SendRequest(CmdId cmdID, object data)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource(1000);
            TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(source.Token);
            
            Request(cmdID, seqNr, data);
 
            return await tcs.Task;
        }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's not your Request method that is blocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line is not what you are expecting:

```
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(source.Token);
```

This calls `TaskCompletionSource(object state)` constructor, which simply sets the `Task.AsyncState` property, which is the legacy `IAsyncResult.AsyncState` implementation, and has nothing to do with cancellation.

The `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` simply makes possible to create an uncompleted task and set its result (or canceled/error state) manually, which features are not publicly available on the `Task` itself.

At this line:

```
return await tcs.Task;
```

the awaiting will never return since you never set the result.

***Solution 1:***

If `Request` is a blocking, synchronous call, you can simply replace the body to something like this:

```
return Task.Run(() => Request(cmdID, seqNr, data, source.Token));
```

Please note though:

- This is not an elegant way to make something asynchronous as it uses a pool thread to execute `Request`
- I added a new `CancellationToken` parameter, which you need to poll often enough

***Solution 2:***

If you really want to use `TaskCompletionSource` you had better make it a field, start sending the request, subscribe whatever events for the respond where you can set the result accordingly and return the created uncompleted `tcs.Task` immediately. I will not copy-paste an earlier answer of mine but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56215328/5114784) you can find en example.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems to work well now and I understand the usage of TCS much better. Why I used the cancellation token in the TCS constructor, no idea, I guess I misread it somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

This usage:

```cs
TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(source.Token);
```

simply sets the `AsyncState` of the task. It has nothing to do with cancellation, and nothing automatic will be hooked. If you want the cancellation to do something, you need to use the `Register` method on the cancellation token, and actually trigger the TCS to become cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is certainly a misunderstanding regarding the relationship between the [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1) and the [`CancellationToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken). The `TaskCompletionSource` is used to create a `Task` that can be controlled manually and directly. Controlling the controller with another controller (a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource)) is not supported, because it makes no sense. There is no `TaskCompletionSource` constructor with a `CancellationToken` parameter.